# SQL query to find sum of a column

Tags: sql

I have a table where I have to get the output as follows:

```
ID - amount - TotalAmount  
1  - 400    - 400  
2 -  600    - 1000  
3 -  400    - 1400
```

The table has two columns: ID & amount. The 'TotalAmount' should be created when the SQL script runs and hope, the rest of the sum is cleared from the above.

How can I do the above sum?? Please share ideas to do so. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a cumulative sum.  The ANSI standard method is as follows:

```
select id, amount, sum(amount) over (order by id) as TotalAmount
from t;
```

Most, but not all databases, support this syntax.

The above is the "right" solution.  If your database doesn't support it, then a correlated subquery is one method:

```
select t.id, t.amount,
       (select sum(t2.amount) from t t2 where t2.id <= t.id) as TotalAmount
from t;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Gordon Linoff. The second query worked.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't state your DBMS, so this is ANSI SQL:

```
select id, amount, 
       sum(amount) over (order by id) as totalamount
from the_table
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL SERVER 2012 this Query is working fine. Try This:

```
SELECT 
   ID, 
   AMOUNT, 
   SUM(AMOUNT) 
   OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS TotalAmount
FROM 
   YourTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, amount, sum(amount) as totalAmount from table_name order by id;
```